# How to install application on Android 2.2 which is being run in VMware Workstation 8.0?

Tags: android

I have [Android 2.2 for x86](http://www.android-x86.org/) which I installed in VMWare Workstation environment. How can I install custom build application?

Can I connect Eclipse debug tools to Android run on VMWare Workstaion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find the IP address of the android VM, by going to the console (Alt-F1) and then typing: `netcfg`, you can go back to the UI by pressing (Alt-F7).

Then type:

```
adb connect <VM's IP>:5555
```

then:

```
adb install path-to-the-apk
```

Comment: Does this work? Can we actually install an app to a phone by knowing its ip? Is'nt this a security compromise?

Comment: Yes it works if you have a rooted phone and if you install and activate adbWireless. Otherwise it cannot be done on a phone, because on a phone adb works only through USB.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing [Astro file manager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en). On mobile devices it lets you find the APK on the SD card and then install it. I assume the same can be done by your emulator.